# I want to create testimonial like below image in html

Tags: jquery, html

Please help me how to create this type of testimonial in html.

[image]

Comment: create three divs. rotate divs to 45 deg. you will get what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can create it using CSS pseudo elements (:before or :after). I did a quick HTML structure, check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mndsilva/pasvsmmt/23/)

CSS:

```
.profile {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.profile::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 640px;
  height: 393px;
  top: -100px;
  left: -200px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/06/26/15/00/seascape-2444040_640.jpg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="profile">
  <!-- Overlay div content goes here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is really help for me. (y)